# transition effects not happening in Firefox and Opera

Tags: firefox, css, opera, gecko, css-transitions

i tried to create a drop down menu effect using transition effects in css3 .the effects were not being produced in firefox and opera although it was in safari and chrome

for transition i used
o-transition:height 0.5s;
-webkit-transition:height 0.5s;
-moz-transition:height 0.5s;

and the browser i used was mozilla 3.6.15 and opera 10.63
so please help me why is the transition effect not happening in firefox

Answer (score 2):

Wasn't `-moz-transition` added to Firefox in version 4.0?  And, it may well be a type, but you've specified `o-transition` in the question, when it is meant to be `-o-transition`.

**Source**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-transition

Answer (score 0):

Opera 10.63 is old, please upgrade to 11.01 or 11.10. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Opera 10.63 is old, but it does support transitions with the -o- (not o-) vendor prefix.

Nick is also correct that Mozilla transitions are only supported in Firefox 4+.